# TravelFailure on Unreal Engine 4

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Hello i am working on a project at my company. We have built an game for VR environment and we want to make it multiplayer. Everything is working but when we are joining a session it gives the "`TravelFailure`"

I have already looked on google they suggested some changes on defaultengine.ini file like adding this

```
"[OnlineSubsystem]
DefaultPlatformService=Null"
```

line or 
`+NetDriverDefinitions=(DefName="GameNetDriver",DriverClassName="OnlineSubsystemSteam.SteamNetDriver",DriverClassNameFallback="OnlineSubsystemUtils.IpNetDriver")` this line
but it didn't worked.

and here is the message log:

> TravelFailure: LoadMapFailure, Reason for Failure: 'Failed to load
>   package '/Game/MultiUserViewer/Maps/UEDPIE_0_map''

. Shutting down PIE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining another session from PIE is not fully supported and often troublesome. The reason is the PIE prefix you see in the map name - this is appended by the engine to the temporary map that is copied just for youe PIE session. You should either do networking tests in PIE starting with multiple users, or run different PCs in standalone and have them connect.